# Trying loop through a List in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to loop through the results of a select statement in LINQ to SQL and insert the result into a table. I'm using a `for` loop to do the iteration but it keeps on taking the first result and doesn't insert the second value. Here is what I have tried.

```
//Get the admin info from AdminContactInfoViews table
var GetAdmin = (from ur in db.AdminContactInfoViews
                where ur.PropertyName == "Telephone" && ur.RoleName == Properties.Settings.Default.Admin
                select ur).ToList();


for (int i = 0; i < GetAdmin.Count; i++)
{
    Alert Notification = (from m in db.Alerts where m.Id == Properties.Settings.Default.NewUserRegistration select m).FirstOrDefault();
    string EmailText = Notification.Email.Replace("%RTSSAdmin%", GetAdmin.FirstOrDefault().Username);
    string SMSText = Notification.Sms.Replace("%RTSSAdmin%", GetAdmin.FirstOrDefault().Username);




    AlertNotification StoreEmail = new AlertNotification
    {
        Sender = Properties.Settings.Default.NoReplyEmail,
        Receiver = GetAdmin[i].Email,
        Subject = Notification.SubjectEmail,
        Message = EmailText,
        NotificationTypeId = Properties.Settings.Default.emailnotification,
        NotificationStatusId = 0,
        ModifiedBy = "SYSTEM",
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
        SentDate = DateTime.Now,

    };
    db.AlertNotifications.InsertOnSubmit(StoreEmail);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your code next time you post. Use the preview to look at what everyone else will see, and ask yourself whether that's what *you'd* want to see if you were trying to help.

Comment: Which part doesnt work? Does `GetAdmin` contain what you think it does? Is count greater than 1? Have you tried setting a breakpoint?

Comment: What is your `mails` variable` there for?

Comment: There is nothing in your Alert Notification Linq that changes on each loop so you will always get the same value.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a loop to go through your list, you need to actually use the element of that loop index. `GetAdmin[i]` is correct, `GetAdmin.FirstOrDefault()` is getting you the first, not the current.

Generally speaking, if you are using a for-loop in C# you are probably doing it the hard way when there is an easy way in form of the foreach-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GetAdmin.Count; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(GetAdmin[i]);
}
```

could be

```
foreach(var admin in GetAdmin)
{
  Console.WriteLine(admin);
}
```

Comment: `GetAdmin.FirstOrDefault()` isn't actually relevant, because the `mails` variable isn't used. In `StoreEmail`, the OP *is* using `GetAdmin[i].Email`. I agree that a foreach loop would be simpler though - and selecting just the emails would make it even more straightforward.

Comment: @JonSkeet but some of the data in the inserted object is build from `.FirstOrDefault()`: Follow the values that lead to the final value of `Message` for example.

Comment: Eek - I hadn't even seen the stuff that had scrolled off the side. Well spotted.

Comment: thank you guy. its working now. i forgot to change the .FirstOrDefault. the foreach statement also work well. @JonSkeet apology for the format. i will put some effort for the formatting next time. thanks Once again guys.